# Parse - Multiple Nested Queries

Tags: parse-platform

I am writing a javascript code using **Parse**. I have **User** class, **Subscription** class and **Favorite** class. All users' subscription information is stored on **Subscription** class and their favorite item information is stored on **Favorite** class so it is like one to many relationship respectively.

I would like to retrieve user information, each user's subscription count and it's favorite item count and store them in an object array.

What I have tried is as follows:

```
    query.find().then(function(objects) {
        return objects;
    }).then(function (objects) {

        objects.forEach(function(object) {

            var subscription = Parse.Object.extend('Subscription');
            var queryForSubscription = new Parse.Query(subscription);
            queryForSubscription.equalTo('subscriptionUser', object);           
            queryForSubscription.find().then(function(subscriptions) {

            var userEmail = object.get('email');
            var subscriptionCount = subscriptions.length;

            var sub = [
                userEmail,
                subscriptionCount
            ];
            userArray.push(sub);
        }
    });
```

This code works well to get **Subscription** count but I am not too sure how I can also get **Favorite** count in parallel and save it into the array at the same time.

For example,there are User A and User B and the expected result will look like this in the end:

```
    [{User A's email, A's subscription count, A's favorite count},
    {User B's email, B's subscription count, B's favorite count}]
```

I am not too sure where to put a new query for Favourite class...Need your advice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What if you kept columns, say in the User class, that kept count of subscriptions and favorites?  So, when user clicks "favorite", a request is made to increment the respective column (there is a handy parseObject.increment("key") method available).  This would save you a call or two in queries per user.  If you returned 4 users, that's the difference between 4 queries and 12.

Or, instead of using queryForSubscription.find(), you could use queryForSubscription.count().  This would save a lot of information being requested so you would get the number right away instead of having to do queryResult.length;

I apologize for not answering the question you wanted.  I suck with promises syntax, but here's an effort nesting the next query:

```
  query.find().then(function(objects) {
    return objects;
}).then(function (objects) {

    objects.forEach(function(object) {

        var subscription = Parse.Object.extend('Subscription');
        var queryForSubscription = new Parse.Query(subscription);
        queryForSubscription.equalTo('subscriptionUser', object);           
        queryForSubscription.count().then(function(subscriptionCount) {

            var favorite = Parse.Object.extend('Favorite');
            var queryForFavorite = new Parse.Query(favorite);
            queryForFavorite.equalTo('favoriteUser', object);           
            queryForFavorite.count().then(function(favoritesCount) {

                var userEmail = object.get('email');
                //var subscriptionCount = subscriptions.length; //used count instead

                var sub = [
                userEmail,
                subscriptionCount,
                favoritesCount
                ];
                userArray.push(sub);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! the reason that I used "find()" instead of "count()" was because i need some other column from **Subscription** class. Sorry I should have mentioned this earlier! I am not too sure if it is a good approach to have extra two columns that keep a count for each class...i am a very SQL-oriented person so prolly too dumb to understand Parse Objects / Queries